# Regex to remove string between two characters (exclusive)

Tags: java, regex

If I have a string `blah.t!@Z8-st?` how can I remove the string between the characters `.` and `?` in Java?

so the resulting text would be `blah.?`

I have got the following but it is inclusive:

```
String s = "blah.t!@Z8-st?";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\..*?\\?", ""));
```

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: Some effort from your side would be much appreciated by all.

Comment: @user86834 and you already have a couple of correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this looks like a contest to "write the most complex regex", let me submit my modest contribution.

```
System.out.println("blah.t!@Z8-st?".replaceAll("\\..*?\\?", ".?"));
```

#### Update

After your edit it appears that you already have the exact same regex as mine, so the only thing you need to fix is the "replace with" part, where you keep the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
String repl = string.replaceAll("^(.*?\\.)[^?]*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **String** replaceAll method with following pattern:

**Pattern**

```
(?<=\.).*(?=\?)
```

**Code**

```
String s = "blah.t!@Z8-st?asdas";
System.out.println(s.ReplaceAll("(?<=\\.).*(?=\\?)", ""));
```